# SQL Server stored procedure error handling with if exists

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have five databases, In that three databases having column Countries and two databases having column Countryrelease..

I am using a cursor, so if I use exists that particular column is throwing an error that column not exists how to handle this one.

Syntax

```
if exists(select 1 from table where column name='Countries')
    select do some operation
else
    select do some operation
```

Comment: I'm not sure what u want, it would be better if you rephrase the question.
As per my understanding, u want to access 5 different database in a Stored Procedure. 
This code can be used to check column exist ->
select 1 from DatabaseName.Schema.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
where column_name = 'countries'

Answer (score 1):

You want to make use of the meta data within the SQL instance.

This will work for you ...

```
if (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YourTableName' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Countries') = 1
    -- The "Countries" column exists
    select do some operation
else
    select do some operation
```

Comment: Super Thank you

Comment: No worries. If it works, be sure to mark it as the correct answer, it then helps others. Thanks